# Call build on Text widget when I change tab

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

I want to change the title in AppBar, when when I switch from one tab to another. In my current code do not do that because on the change tab build is not called.

Thanks to all!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/task.dart';
import '../widgets/tasks_list_mob.dart';
import '../widgets/new_task.dart';

class TaskListName {
  final String shortName;
  final String longName;
  TaskListName(this.shortName, this.longName);
}

class TaksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaksScreenState createState() => _TaksScreenState();
}

class _TaksScreenState extends State<TaksScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  final Map<int, TaskListName> tasksListLabels = {
    0: TaskListName('Backlog', 'Tasks in backlog'),
    1: TaskListName('Tomorrow', 'Planed tasks for tomorrow'),
    2: TaskListName('Today', 'Your tasks for today'),
    3: TaskListName('Last work day', 'Tasks completed last working day'),
    4: TaskListName('Completed', 'Completed Tasks'),
    5: TaskListName('Backlog', 'Archived not completed tasks'),
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> showAddTaskDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    print(_tabController);
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
        children: [NewTask(TaksBucket.backlog)],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tasks = Provider.of<List<Task>>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(tasksListLabels[_tabController.index].longName),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[0].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[1].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[2].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[3].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[4].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[5].shortName),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.backlog),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.tomorrow),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.today),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.completed),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.completed),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.archived),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => showAddTaskDialog(context),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

After @mkobuolys solution implementation - the scroll handle is still missing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/task.dart';
import '../widgets/tasks_list_mob.dart';
import '../widgets/new_task.dart';

class TaskListName {
  final String shortName;
  final String longName;
  TaskListName(this.shortName, this.longName);
}

class TaksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaksScreenState createState() => _TaksScreenState();
}

class _TaksScreenState extends State<TaksScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  var _tabIndex = ValueNotifier(2);
  final Map<int, TaskListName> tasksListLabels = {
    0: TaskListName('Backlog', 'Tasks in backlog'),
    1: TaskListName('Tomorrow', 'Planed tasks for tomorrow'),
    2: TaskListName('Today', 'Your tasks for today'),
    3: TaskListName('Last work day', 'Tasks completed last working day'),
    4: TaskListName('Completed', 'Completed Tasks'),
    5: TaskListName('Backlog', 'Archived not completed tasks'),
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
  }

  Future<void> showAddTaskDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
        children: [NewTask(TaksBucket.backlog)],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tasks = Provider.of<List<Task>>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: **ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _tabIndex,
          builder: (context, value, child) =>
              Text(tasksListLabels[value].longName),
        ),**
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          onTap: (value) {
            _tabIndex.value = _tabController.index;
          },
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[0].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[1].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[2].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[3].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[4].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[5].shortName),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.backlog),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.tomorrow),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.today),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.completed),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.completed),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.archived),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => showAddTaskDialog(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At the end it was really easy to make it done!

- I did create ValueNotifier _tabIndex
- At init state I addListener on TabControler. Listener set value for _tabIndex(ValueNotifier). I did dispose Listener in dispose...
- In the build method add ValueListenableBuilder to the title.
- Final code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/task.dart';
import '../widgets/tasks_list_mob.dart';
import './tasks_notifications_screen.dart';
import '../widgets/new_task.dart';
import '../widgets/count_batch_icon_button.dart';
import '../consts/consts.dart';
import '../util/tasks_helper.dart';

class TaskListName {
  final String shortName;
  final String longName;
  final TaksBucket bucket;
  TaskListName(this.shortName, this.longName, this.bucket);
}

class TaksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaksScreenState createState() => _TaksScreenState();
}

class _TaksScreenState extends State<TaksScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  var _tabIndex = ValueNotifier(2);

  final Map<int, TaskListName> tasksListLabels = {
    0: TaskListName('Backlog', 'Tasks in backlog', TaksBucket.backlog),
    1: TaskListName(
        'Tomorrow', 'Planed tasks for tomorrow', TaksBucket.tomorrow),
    2: TaskListName('Today', 'Your tasks for today', TaksBucket.today),
    3: TaskListName('Last work day', 'Tasks completed last working day',
        TaksBucket.completed),
    4: TaskListName('Completed', 'Completed Tasks', TaksBucket.completed),
    5: TaskListName(
        'Archived', 'Archived not completed tasks', TaksBucket.archived),
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      _tabIndex.value = _tabController.index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.removeListener(() {
      _tabIndex.value = _tabController.index;
    });
  }

  Future<void> showAddTaskDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
        children: [NewTask(tasksListLabels[_tabController.index].bucket)],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tasks = Provider.of<List<Task>>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _tabIndex,
          builder: (context, value, child) =>
              Text(tasksListLabels[value].longName),
        ),
        actions: [
          CountBatchIconButton(
            TasksHelper.numberOfTasksForNotification(tasks),
            Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TasksNotifications.routeName),
          ),
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorColor: TaskConsts.mainColor,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[0].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[1].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[2].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[3].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[4].shortName),
            Tab(text: tasksListLabels[5].shortName),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.backlog),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.tomorrow),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.today),
          TasksListMob(
            tasks,
            TaksBucket.completed,
            isLastWorkingDay: true,
          ),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.completed),
          TasksListMob(tasks, TaksBucket.archived),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: TaskConsts.mainColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => showAddTaskDialog(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `TabBar` widget, add `onTap` callback with the `setState` method to trigger rebuild, hence updating the name:

```
...
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text(tasksListLabels[_tabController.index].longName),
  bottom: TabBar(
    controller: _tabController,
    isScrollable: true,
    tabs: [
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[0].shortName),
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[1].shortName),
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[2].shortName),
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[3].shortName),
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[4].shortName),
      Tab(text: tasksListLabels[5].shortName),
    ],
    onTap: (_) {
      setState((){});
    },
  ),
),
...
```

Comment: That partialy work :-). Thank you @mkobuolys! I did use ValueNotifier instead of set state, but It still not handle scroll event.  I did update original post.

Comment: If you want to change the tab view (with scroll), you can use `_tabController.animateTo(newIndex, Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.easeInOut)` where `newIndex` is the index of the tab you want to go to (just adjust parameters based on your needs, of course).

Comment: I did enable it with isScrollable: true, on TabBar. My problem is how to build title on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same text of your tab where you switching with the help of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a provider to make/view the changes without rebuilding the whole page

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30843885)

Answer (score -1):

Simple.
After you calling *async* method, when you calling **Navigator.of(context).pop()** or **Navigator.pop(context)**, use these as below.

```
if(mounted){
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have a sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).